# Perl, append an element to an existing SOAP::Data element

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, soaplite

I'm struggling with Perl (v5.24.1) SOAP::Lite. i'm trying to add an element to
an existing Data element. 
Assume i have the following construct:

```
use SOAP::Lite + qw/ trace /;  
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new( proxy => 'http://soap.server.com');
$soap->on_action( sub { "http://tempuri.org/some" });
$soap->autotype(0)->readable(1);
$soap->default_ns('http://tempuri.org/');
$som = $soap->call('GetItems', SOAP::Data->name('Store')->attr( { 'xmlns'    => 'Some.Structs'} )->value(
\SOAP::Data->value(
 SOAP::Data->name('Items')->value(
  \SOAP::Data->value(
   SOAP::Data->name('Available')->value('false'),
   SOAP::Data->name('Apple')->value('1'),
   SOAP::Data->name('Orange')->value('2'),
  )),
 )),   
);
```

But now i'd like to add 'N' Elements of **Items**, i want to this in a loop based on conditions so thats just an example, i tried the following:

```
 use SOAP::Lite + qw/ trace /;  
 my $soap = SOAP::Lite->new( proxy => 'http://soap.server.com');
 $soap->on_action( sub { "http://tempuri.org/some" });
 $soap->autotype(0)->readable(1);
 $soap->default_ns('http://tempuri.org/');

 my $data1= (SOAP::Data->name('Store')->attr( { 'xmlns' => 'Some.Structs'} )->value(
   \SOAP::Data->value(
    SOAP::Data->name('Items')->value(
     \SOAP::Data->value(
     SOAP::Data->name('Available')->value('false'),
     SOAP::Data->name('Apple')->value('1'),
     SOAP::Data->name('Orange')->value('2'),
    )),
  )),   
 );
 my $data2= (SOAP::Data->name('Store')->attr( { 'xmlns' => 'Some.Structs'} )->value(
   \SOAP::Data->value(
    SOAP::Data->name('Items')->value(
     \SOAP::Data->value(
     SOAP::Data->name('Available')->value('true'),
     SOAP::Data->name('Bananas')->value('4'),
     SOAP::Data->name('Pineapple')->value('2'),
    )),
  )),   
 );
```

Now trying to add the element

```
push $data1->value, data2;
```

Or

```
push ($data1,$data1);
```

The return is:
**Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden ....**

Finally, when the elements are joined i'd like to send them but i'm not sure if this would work:

```
$som = $soap->call('GetItems', $data1);
```

Any help would be much appreciated ....

Answer (score 1):

The answer in [Append an element to an already existing SOAP::Data complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077539/append-an-element-to-an-already-existing-soapdata-complex-type?rq=1) used an experimental style of dereferencing (now fixed). You need to use the following syntax:

```
push @{ $data1->value }, $data2
```

To append to the `Items` list after the fact, you can use the following approach that manually walks down the data structure you constructed above and appends to the list in question:

```
push @{ ${ ${ $data1->value }->value->value }->{_value} }, $data2;
```

But I think you're much better off by constructing your SOAP data only once you have all the payload data together. In the case of a loop, instead structure your program as follows:

```
my @payload;
for my $item (@items) {
    push @payload, SOAP::Data->name( $item->{name} )->value( $item->{count}) if $item->{wanted};
};

my $soap = SOAP::Data->value( \@payload );
```

Answer (score 0):

On the above sample I tried

```
push @{ $data1->value }, $data2;
```

But that results into

> Not an ARRAY reference at ..

---

As suggested from above i will construct my data like:

```
my @payload;
push @payload, SOAP::Data->name('Store')->attr( { 'xmlns' => 'Some.Structs'} 
 )->value(
 \SOAP::Data->value(
 SOAP::Data->name('Items')->value(
  \SOAP::Data->value(
  SOAP::Data->name('Available')->value('false'),
  SOAP::Data->name('Apple')->value('1'),
  SOAP::Data->name('Orange')->value('2'),
 )),
));

#Now add the next element
push @payload, SOAP::Data->name('Store')->attr( { 'xmlns' => 'Some.Structs'} 
)->value(
\SOAP::Data->value(
 SOAP::Data->name('Items')->value(
  \SOAP::Data->value(
  SOAP::Data->name('Available')->value('false'),
  SOAP::Data->name('Orange')->value('1'),
  SOAP::Data->name('Pianaple')->value('2'),
 )),
));
$som = $soap->call('GetItems', \@payload);
```

Comment: As far as I understand SOAP::Data , you can't later on decide that you want to convert a scalar item to a list item. If your real intention is to append to the `Items` list, then you need to walk down the constucted data structure and patch that value in (see my updated reply above)